# Swiftmailer working on localhost but not in production

Tags: php, html-email, swiftmailer

On my localhost (Linux Mint OS) Swiftmailer is working fine with the following code, but whenever I move it up to my server is just hangs at the send function and then gives me an internal server error.

I currently have my email setup through Google Apps, so maybe SMTP will not work for this situation? If thats the case, how do you suggest I change this from SMTP.

Also, whenever I send an email like this, it is showing up with a from address of the one in the username area. I want it to show up with the from address in the "setFrom" function.

```
//Include the swiftmailer class
require_once 'comm/swiftmailer/swift_required.php';

//Create a message
//Pass it as a parameter when you create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('My Subject');
$message->setFrom(array('noreply@domain.com' => 'No Reply'));
$message->setTo(array('me@domain.com' => 'Me'));
$message->setBody($emailContent, 'text/html');

//Create transport class and email the message
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('useracctname')->setPassword('password');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: who is your server host?

Comment: seems like you are trying to use gmail for your smtp and i know for a fact that godaddy have restriction with it.

Comment: @kjy112: So what is another way to do this? Swiftmailer recommends that you use SMTP over the other two transport types. But maybe I need to change some setting with my DNS zone editor so that the local mail server sends these, and the gmail account gets the rest?

Comment: Look in the server logs to see what the internal error is about.

Comment: @Pekka: I dont think I have access to any logs. I tried looking in the root directory but I do not see anything that stands out.

Comment: Hmm. Does Google offer an alternative port? It could be that your provider blocks outgoing traffic on that port.

Comment: @Pekka Thats a great question. I am wondering though, could it be that I am not using the local mail server so it wont allow SMTP? Or is that not how it works? Also, what about using one of the other transport types? Do you think I should just continue to try and get this one to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a port problem on the server. Port 465 could be closed to prevent spamming. It could also be that the server's version of PHP lacks SSL support.

> I am wondering though, could it be that I am not using the local mail server so it wont allow SMTP?

If you address gmail as explicitly as you do, it's very unlikely you're using another transport type or a different server.

> Also, what about using one of the other transport types?

I think SMTP is your only option to get it running with Gmail. It could, however, be that your server is providing a `mail()` based service (obviously with a different sender address than GMail though). In that case, you may be able to use Swiftmailer's [`mail` transport](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/mail-transport).

Comment: What I meant is that I have my MX records setup for google apps, so would that mean that SMTP is disabled? Or is it most likely a port problem? Sorry I am not very good with all of these protocols and how the work.

Comment: It also seems like mail() is highly discouraged so I was trying to do what is recommended, do you think I would be ok using mail()?

Comment: @Metropolis you might have to ask your provider for what is wrong exactly, it's extremely hard to debug without knowing the 500 error. If you send a small number of mails (no bulk mail), `mail()` is okay.

Comment: @Pekka I talked to the host and they did have the port blocked! Also Pekka, would you be able to answer part 2 of my question? Where the from address is showing up as my username/password instead of the setFrom Address? I already tried setReplyto also, but that just added both addresses. Thanks a ton for your help on this.

Comment: @Metropolis you shouldn't, and often can't, set an arbitrary "from" address - it is one of the top signs for spam and will be swallowed by many filters. If you need to use GMail and want to specify a different sender address, it's best to use `reply-to`.

Comment: @Metropolis how did you solve your problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Also, @Pekka the link in your answer is dead

Comment: @CarrieKendall My hosting company was blocking the port. Once they stopped blocking it everything was good

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem : I was able to send gmail email in local (after updating that configuration : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps ) but not in production.

To fix my problem I've **logged to my gmail account with my production ip** / from my production server and answer the gmail security question.

One of the solution to log to your gmail account with your production ip, is to

1. open an ssh tunnel (ssh -2NfCT -D 5000 yoursshuser@yourdomain.org)
2. configure you browser to use that proxy (eg Firefox :to Preferences > Advanced > Network > Settings > Manual proxy configuration > SOCKS Hosts: localhost / Post: 5000 / SOCKS v5 )
3. log to you gmail account as usual

The error outputed by Symfony was :

```
app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "joe.doe" using 1 possible authenticators [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

well, here is the solution.

if you are sending SMTP mail you should create email account at the server then use this email info at your code.
 the server will not send the email if you don't have valid email account to send using it
when you use "from".
 this should be a true correct email account a fake one.

the only possible reason to send using fake account is using mail() function.